# The definition of a widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, widget

How would you define a widget? I see "widget" being used to describe things that I've seen also described as components such as buttons, text fields, forms, etc. Jquery UI refers to things like this as widgets, however I've always heard widgets being referred to as "mini applications". Is it that "widgets" have different meanings for different cases? What would make a UI element qualify as a widget or component or just a UI element? Is it all the same?

Comment: `Widget - a small gadget or mechanical device, esp. one whose name is unknown or unspecified.` It sounds like the entire purpose of the word `Widget` is to be ambiguous.

Comment: Like saying "This thing" you add?

Comment: Exactly, `widget` is just a general term, think of it as a synonym for `thing`